# How to access a model function using a controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Can you help me with this? I am creating my own login process using Laravel. By the way I am still new in Laravel and I really have don't enough knowledge.

My scenario is I created a code with a parameter inside my controller which can access a model function. And this model function will find if the user data is correct or matched in the database. But I haven't created it yet. I just want to see if the data from my parameter is accessible in the model.

The problem is in the model I can't access the parameter value.

Here's my code:

In my controller

```
public function login() {

    $rules = array(
        'employee_id'       =>  'required',
        'employee_password' =>  'required'
    );

    $validate_login = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    if($validate_login->fails()) {

        $messages = $validate_login->messages();

        return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($messages);

    } else {

        $userdata = array(
            'id'        =>  Input::get('employee_id'),
            'password'  =>  Hash::make(Input::get('employee_password'))
        );

        $validateDetail = Employee::ValidateLogin($userdata); //pass parameter to model

    }

}
```

Here's the model function

```
public function scopeValidateLogin($data) 
{
    fd($data); //fd() is my own custom helper for displaying array with exit()
}
```

Inside the scopeValidateLogin() function I am planning to use Query Builder to validate the login.

Here's my route

```
Route::model('employee','Employee');

Route::get('/','EmployeesController@index');
Route::get('/register', 'EmployeesController@register');

Route::post('/login','EmployeesController@login');
Route::post('/handleRegister', function() 
            {

                $rules = array(
                    'emp_code'      =>  'numeric',
                    'lastname'      =>  'required|min:2|max:15',
                    'firstname'     =>  'required|min:2|max:20',
                    'middlename'    =>  'min:1|max:20',
                    'password'      =>  'required|min:8|max:30',
                    'cpassword'     =>  'required|same:password'
                );

                $validate_register = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

                if($validate_register->fails()) {

                    $messages = $validate_register->messages();

                    return Redirect::to('register')
                                        ->withErrors($messages)
                                        ->withInput(Input::except('password','cpassword'));

                } else {

                    $employee = new Employee;

                    $employee->emp_code     = Input::get('emp_code');
                    $employee->lastname     = Input::get('lastname');
                    $employee->firstname    = Input::get('firstname');
                    $employee->middlename   = Input::get('middlename');
                    $employee->gender       = Input::get('gender');
                    $employee->birthday     = Input::get('birthday');
                    $employee->password     = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));

                    $employee->save();

                    Session::flash('success_notification','Success: The account has been successfully created!');

                    return Redirect::action('EmployeesController@index');

                }

            }
        );
```

Now after running fd($data) my browser load a series of arrays and then it will crash.
I don't know what's happening but I think it is sending multiple request to my model.

Am I doing the right way of accessing the model inside the controller? Or are there any best approach with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the MVC framework incorrectly. You should be evaluating the input and login inside of the controller not with a method inside a model.

Comment: So you mean I do the validation inside the controller? What I understand about MVC is every transaction in the database you made should be in the Model.

Comment: Generally a model represents a table, but the actually execution of the authentication logic should be placed within the controller. Here is a good authentication demo with Laravel: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/authentication-with-laravel-4--net-35593